Solving $\int \frac{7^{\frac 3{x^2}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{14}} -6}{2x^3} dx$ with Basic Integration Techniques
I'm trying to do this integral: $\int \frac{7^{\frac 3{x^2}}-\sqrt[3]{x^{14}} -6}{2x^3} dx$. But I get stuck here: $\int {7^{\frac 3{x^2}}\over{2x^3}} -{{\sqrt[3]{x^{14}}\over{2x^3}}} - {6\over{2x^3}} dx$.
I'm having trouble with this part, I can't think of a way to integrate it and  I can only integrate it using basic integration or change of variables: ${7^{\frac 3{x^2}}\over{2x^3}}$
I don't know if I'm missing a step or doing something wrong, so help would be appreciated

This can be solved using substitution. Here’s how I thought of solving it:
Let $u=x^2$, which leaves us with $\int\frac{7^{\frac{3}{u}}}{2u^2}du$
Now substitute again, let $v=\frac{3}{u}$ leaving us with $\int -\frac{7^v}{3}dv$
From here we can use basic integration rules to solve.

Alternate substitution: $u=\frac 3{x^2}, du=\frac {-6}{x^3}dx$.

With the $u=x^2$ substitution, it should be $4u^2$ in the first denominator, i.e., $\int \frac{7^{\frac3u}}{4u^2}\mathrm du$.
